# Codeigniter model not loading

Tags: codeigniter, model

I'm a newbe in codeigniter.
something is going wrong with I think the model.

this is the controler:

```
<?php

class Fuel extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
     $this->load->helper('html');
     $this->load->library('table');
}

public function image() {
$data['title'] = 'test';
$data['main_content'] = 'imagetest';
$this->load->view("template", $data);
}

public function overview() {
    $this->load->model('Get_DB');
    $this->Get_DB->overview() ;
    $data['title'] = 'overview';
    $data['main_content'] = 'overview';
    $this->load->view("template", $data);
    }
```

when I load the image function, it works just fine, but the function overview is the problem.

this is my model:

```
    <?php

class Get_DB extends CI_Model 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function overzicht() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM invoer "
        . "ORDER BY datum DESC");
        $gen_query = $this->table->generate($query);
        return $gen_query;
    }
}
```

and this is my view:

```
    <?php

echo $gen_query;
```

and if you want to know: my template is this:

```
<?php

$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view($main_content);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

now when I open my view I get this message:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: gen_query Filename:
>   views/overzicht.php Line Number: 3

in the model you see that I have made a var $gen_query
so why is that undifined?

regards,

Ralph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
public function overview() {
    $this->load->model('Get_DB');
    $data                   = array();
    $data['gen_query']      = $this->Get_DB->overzicht() ; #corrected model function and save the result in `gen_query`
    $data['title']          = 'overview';
    $data['main_content']   = 'overview';
    $this->load->view("template", $data);
}
```

Comment: Yes that one works, thank you very much.
but why use:
        $data                   = array();
if I skip that part, it still works

Comment: It's just a good practice, to initialize an array with `array();`... if your assignments to `$data` fail, you still have an array

Answer (score 0):

In Controler:

```
public function overview() {
    $this->load->model('Get_DB');
    $result  = $this->Get_DB->overview() ;
    $data['title'] = 'overview';
    $data['main_content'] = 'overview';
    $data['re'] = $result;
    $this->load->view("template", $data);
    }
```

And In view page you can retrive the result

like

```
foreach($re->result() as $row)
{
    //You can get each row data here  $row->your_field_names

}
```